# How can I remove bower from this project and use requirejs with yarn (noob)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, bower, yarnpkg

How can I switch this to avoid using bower?

I installed yeoman for the first time and the generator for knockoutjs use bower. Now I read bower support is limited and bootstrap use popper.js which in v2 will deprecate support for bower. I would like to avoid the headache now and learn at the same time.

RequireJS and every client side libraries is in `/src/bower_modules`.

If I install bootstrap using npm or yarn it will install them in `/node_modules`, which the browser doesn't have access.
Do I then use gulp to transfer the dist folder to my `/src/bower_modules` folder?

Folder structure:

```
/src/
  |--bower_modules/
  |--app/
      |--require.config.js
/node_modules/
/gulpfile.js
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var requireJsRuntimeConfig = vm.runInNewContext(fs.readFileSync('src/app/require.config.js') + '; require;'),
    requireJsOptimizerConfig = merge(requireJsRuntimeConfig, {
        out: 'scripts.js',
        baseUrl: './src',
        name: 'app/startup',
        paths: {
            requireLib: 'bower_modules/requirejs/require'
        },
        include: [
            'requireLib',
            'components/nav-bar/nav-bar',
            'components/home-page/home',
            'text!components/about-page/about.html'
        ],
        insertRequire: ['app/startup'],
        bundles: {
            // If you want parts of the site to load on demand, remove them from the 'include' list
            // above, and group them into bundles here.
            // 'bundle-name': [ 'some/module', 'another/module' ],
            // 'another-bundle-name': [ 'yet-another-module' ]
        }
    }),
    transpilationConfig = {
        root: 'src',
        skip: ['bower_modules/**', 'app/require.config.js'],
        babelConfig: {
            modules: 'amd',
            sourceMaps: 'inline'
        }
    },
    babelIgnoreRegexes = transpilationConfig.skip.map(function(item) {
        return babelCore.util.regexify(item);
    });
```

app/require.config.js:

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: ".",
    paths: {
        "bootstrap":            "bower_modules/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min",
        "crossroads":           "bower_modules/crossroads/dist/crossroads.min",
        "hasher":               "bower_modules/hasher/dist/js/hasher.min",
        "popper":               "bower_modules/popper.js/dist/popper",
        "jquery":               "bower_modules/jquery/dist/jquery",
        "knockout":             "bower_modules/knockout/dist/knockout",
        "knockout-projections": "bower_modules/knockout-projections/dist/knockout-projections",
        "signals":              "bower_modules/js-signals/dist/signals.min",
        "text":                 "bower_modules/requirejs-text/text"
    },
    shim: {
        "bootstrap": { deps: ["popper", "jquery"] }
    }
};
```

Sidenote: The origin of the issue is that I require popper for bootstrap and bootstrasp.bundle is not included in the bower version is seems. Also popper doesn't like bower very much and won't be supported very long. I also have multiple errors trying to include it. I would also like to learn the good way and since bower will not be around long I wouldn't mind not working with it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Bower itself posted a blog about this recently: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/.
Here's the key takeaways:

1. Manually move any packages from `bower.json` to `package.json` that are available from both Bower and NPM
2. For any items that are only available via Bower you can use the [bower-away](https://github.com/sheerun/bower-away) NPM package to install those with NPM instead of Bower
3. Write a task runner script (Grunt/Gulp/etc...) to move the package(s) file(s) to your `dist` directory

Something like this should do it.

`gulp.task('injectNpmPackages', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    path.join('/node_modules/my-package/build/my-package.min.js')
  ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/dist/vendor/'));
});`